# Create and add values dynamically in dropdownlist in MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've a view that displays list structure for the documents uploaded. However, this needs to change to create dropdownlist instead of list. below code creates list

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileId)</td> 
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileName)</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { id=item.FileId})</td>
    </tr>
}
```

This needs to be changed to create a dropdownlist, how can I do that?

Comment: What exactly do you want to display in the dropdown list? FileId? FileName? Download link?

Comment: It's only Filename that would be displayed

Answer (score 1):

You can also use with this

> In controller

```
Public Actionresult HomeController()
{
    // your code goes here
    //create list of content you want to display on dropdown list
    //you can pass it on 2 ways 1. with model pass and 2.is with viewbag 
     Viewbag.countryList = listofCountry;

}
```

> In View

Method1 with Model

```
<select>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<option value="@item.FileId">@ietm.FileName</option>
}
</select>
```

Method 2.

```
<select>
   @foreach(var item in Viewbag.countryList)
   {
          <option value="@item.FileId">@ietm.FileName</option>
   }
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to render a dropdown list from a collection.

Here is how you do it with `DropDownList` helper

```
@Html.DropDownList("MySelect",new SelectList(Model,"FileId","FileName"))
```

This will render a SELECT element with name and Id attribute values set to "MySelect" and the options text will be the `FileName` and value will be the `FileId`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.FileId, model.FileItems.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.FileName, Value = x.FileId })
```